# Problems with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

"user_id" property doesn't get persisted with "OneToOne" in config.
Here is config in yaml:

```
Event:
  type: entity
  table: events
  repositoryClass: EventRepository
  fields:
    userId:
      type: integer
      unsigned: true
      nullable: true
      column: user_id
  oneToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        user_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
      orphanRemoval: false
```

Is it an error to describe "user_id" both in "OneToOne" and in "fields"?
Can it be wrong relation type what prevents "user_id" from saving?

Comment: Maybe it's time to go to a different church?

Comment: Changed "oneToOne" which I selected for simplicity to "manyToOne" which is more appropriate. Now I have problem with SQL Doctrine generates. Like this one "INSERT INTO events (user_id, l)". Wtf is "l"? "user_id" is the last column in the table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I shouldn't have tried to use both "user" and "user_id".
Generally, never use relations, they give you nothing. There is no code generation. And to have Active Record one have to code it.

Comment: Relations are great. You get all in one obeject. $user->getPost()->getName() :)

Comment: They are great if your site has no visitors and you don't care about performance.